# BizTalk: How to get all dlls from an application?

Tags: dll, biztalk

I would like to build an external app (console application) which inform me for the DLLs versions that are used in an BizTalk application.

Of course with a quick search I find some examples which are use the  Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM DLL, 
but these examples shows only the DLLs that exist in [BizTalk_Local_MgmtDb].[dbo].[bts_assembly] table which when I see them in BizTalk health monitor they have type System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly.

I would like also to add in my app (Console application) the DLLs of type System.BizTalk:Assembly which for example can be a helper class which are not listed by Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM because, I guess, they not exist in [BizTalk_Local_MgmtDb].[dbo].[bts_assembly] table

Have someone any idea how I can achieve what I want?

[image: Types]

Comment: i am always adding my helper components as biztalk resources.

Comment: According to health monitor are already in Resources but stil not accessable from ExplorerOM dll and are not in BizTalk_Local_MgmtDb].[dbo].[bts_assembly.

Comment: Good question. Yes, you are right that it isn't in the bts_assembly table.  Rather than writing an application from scratch, you might consider enhancing BizTalk documenter.  I've even added the above as a feature request for this https://github.com/mbrimble/biztalkdocumenter/issues/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found them, these assembles exists in managmentDB in table [BizTalk_Local_MgmtDb].[dbo].[adpl_sat]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question correctly:
You are creating a utility console application, which uses "Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM". And your "helper class Assembly" is not being listed in your "Console application" because it is not of type "System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly".

I'm afraid that you won't be able to do so, as you can't add a class library as "System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly". Here is the error we get when try to do so: [image: Error when adding class library as BziTalk Assembly]

You can make try using "System.Reflection".

Comment: I am quite sure that I am  not able to list the 'helper' dll with the help of ExplorerOM dll. But since Helth Monitor shows this helper dll in resources , means that somehow exists a way to list the helper dll in my utility console application, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Can you be a bit more specific about System.Reflection?

Comment: I'm not sure System.Reflection will help here. Found this blog post which might help you: http://pinhask.blogspot.com/2008/06/dependency-in-biztalk-assembly.html

Answer (score 0):

For your components to be considered as BizTalk Artefacts, your project should be `.btproj`

[image]

Then deploy your components same way you deploy your biztalk applications.